# Laravel: getting stored filename

Tags: laravel

I am storing an uploaded file using the following code on my controller:

```
$stored_file = $request->file('image')->store(Config::get('filesystems.uploads.gallery_dir'));
Log::info($stored_file);
```

The `$stored_file` variable contains the full path of the file once saved, is there a function within Laravel to return just the generated name? (without the path)

Currently `$stored_file` returns `uploads/gallery/wg7Aa4frj8PQkH89oIseMtlpFtruiJNsHTOoretn.jpeg`
I would like to to return `wg7Aa4frj8PQkH89oIseMtlpFtruiJNsHTOoretn.jpeg`

Comment: try $stored_file->getName(), or use php function pathinfo($stored_file)['basename']

Comment: @irza please turn this into an answer, the pathinfo method works as required

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:`pathinfo($stored_file)['basename']`

Answer (score 3):

Considering Laravel 7.x, when you get an uploaded file from request using:

`$file = $request->file('photo');`

You get an UploadedFile file instance back, and when you call "store" method on it. It internally generates a unique name using md5 hash with a function named "hashName".

Therefore if you call "hashName" method on the UploadedFile instance you will get the same unique name that laravel created during your "store" method call.

`$filename = $request->file('photo')->hashName();`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using hashName() this way:

```
$file = $request->file('image');
$url = $file->store('/posts');
echo $file->hashName();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to get rid of what is unnecessary :

```
<?php

  echo str_replace("uploads/gallery/", "", $stored_file); 

?>
```